# Trimmed means ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

For my Bachelor thesis I need to compute a trimmed means ANOVA (2 independent variables with 2 levels each: Motivation (high/low) and condition (we/txt), 1 dependent variable (testscore)). I made an [excel file](https://workupload.com/file/pBBXSBxX) with the summary. Now when I try to compute the ANOVA using `t2way()` R shows me the following error message:

> ```
> error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`tmp`, grp[i], value = c(4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  : replacement has 7 rows, data has 11
> ```

Where did I go wrong? I researched the forum here, watched countless YouTube videos but I could not solve this on my own

[Here](https://workupload.com/file/4h22wav9) is the script I have got so far, maybe that helps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Both the necessary code and necessary data should be in the post, not in external files. Keep in mind the [mcve] guidance while you [edit] to include both those sets of information